# How to expose multiple docker-compose pipelines on available ports?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose pipeline which orchestrates certain containers (nginx on port `8000` for static resources and routes other requests to a backend container running django on gunicorn). I am trying to launch multiple instances of this docker-compose pipeline. The only abstraction that I've managed to find is the `-p option` that defines a "project" name based identifier. However, it won't be able to spin up another instance of the compose pipeline since port `8000` would be used by the first instance. What would be the best option to achieve this?

I don't think that `replicas` or `scale` is what I am looking for.

I want to be able to access `<IP_ADDRESS>:8001` for docker-compose instance 1, `<IP_ADDRESS>:8002` for docker-compose instance 2 and so on. Is this even a good approach?

Unfortunately in this scenario the django app is not designed to handle multiple users for the web app. Hence the need for an alternate strategy for multiplexing connections and linking a user to an entire docker-compose pipeline execution.

Comment: Are you looking to auto-deploy new instances? Or can you just create a new docker-compose-2.yml file and change the nginx port to 8001, 8002, etc.? Are you using `docker run`, `docker compose`, or `docker swarm`?

Comment: I am trying to auto deploy using docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

If you've got Eureka/Zuul I think that *--scale* would be the best option as it will round-robin load-balance your requests and the port it's running on is irrelevant.

If you want to specify the port number then I think you'd have to manually set the expose port number, or script a solution looking for the next available port number in a sequence.  I think this is a crappy approach, however.